# Fastest way to get money in Dragons call?

Tags: dragons-call

I'm playing Dragons Call online, and I'm a mage level 15. What is the fastest way to make a bunch of money? I need about 1,000,000 to buy some good equipments and working/grinding takes a  takes a really long time when you only get a few hundred per enemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the fastest way to get money in Dragon's call is to play Instances and sell whatever gear you get in them.

Another way to get money is to sell some gem which you acquire while fighting monsters.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this was what worked well for me during those days.

Answer (score 0):

Buying the currency online from farmers will always be the fastest way.

Comment: And in most cases, against the EULA.